# Unable to transform value for property path "[open_time]": Expected a \DateTimeInterface

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-3.3

I'm currently trying to create a form so the user can add (multiple) business hours for a company.
The create form work just fine, but the edit form seems to keep throwing the this error.

> Unable to transform value for property path "[open_time]": Expected a
>   \DateTimeInterface.

When I change the "open_time" inside my *BusinessHoursType* form type from *TimeType* to *TextType*. It seems to be working fine. But users will have to enter the data in a text field opposed to the hour/minutes dropdown.
I'm also checking if a specific company is open or not using the time and days entered.

How can I get this to work with TimeType?
I feel like I'm overlooking something small here.

**Business Entity**

```
class Business
{
    use TimestampTrait;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text")
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="website", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     * @Assert\Url()
     */
    private $website;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="phone", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Regex(
     *      pattern="/^((\+|00)32\s?|0)(\d\s?\d{3}|\d{2}\s?\d{2})(\s?\d{2}){2}$/",
     *      message="Gelieve een geldig telefoonnummer in te vullen"
     * )
     */
    //TODO: regex belgian mobile number (/^((\+|00)32\s?|0)4(60|[789]\d)(\s?\d{2}){3}$/)
    private $phone;

    /**
     * @var bool
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="open_24h", type="boolean", options={"default"=false})
     */
    private $open24h;

    /**
     * @var array
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="operation_hours", type="json_array")
     */
    private $businessHours;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="page_views", type="integer", options={"default"=0})
     */
    private $pageViews;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="google_places_place_id", type="string", length=255, nullable=true, unique=true)
     */
    private $googlePlacesPlaceId;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="foursquare_venue_id", type="string", length=255, nullable=true, unique=true)
     */
    private $foursquareVenueId;

    // Member Variables for Relationships.
    // -----------------------------------
    /**
     * Many Businesses have One Merchant.
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Merchant", inversedBy="businesses")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="merchant_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $merchant;

    /**
     * One Business has One Address.
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Address", mappedBy="business")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="address_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *
     * @Assert\Valid()
     */
    private $address;

    /**
     * One Business has many Review.
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Review", mappedBy="business")
     */
    private $reviews;

    /**
     * Many Businesses have One Business Type.
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="BusinessType", inversedBy="businesses")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="businessType_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $businessType;

    /**
     * One Business has Many Images.
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Image", mappedBy="business")
     */
    private $images;

    /**
     * One Business has Many Promotions.
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Promotion", mappedBy="business")
     */
    private $promotions;

    /**
     * One Business has Many Prdocuts.
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Product", mappedBy="business")
     */
    private $products;


    /**
     * Business constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->setCreatedAt(new DateTime());
        $this->setUpdatedAt(new DateTime());

        $this->setPageViews(0);

        $this->setReviews(new ArrayCollection());
        $this->setImages(new ArrayCollection());
        $this->setPromotions(new ArrayCollection());
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Business
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     *
     * @return Business
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Set website
     *
     * @param string $website
     *
     * @return Business
     */
    public function setWebsite($website)
    {
        $this->website = $website;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get website
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getWebsite()
    {
        return $this->website;
    }

    /**
     * Set phone
     *
     * @param string $phone
     *
     * @return Business
     */
    public function setPhone($phone)
    {
        $this->phone = $phone;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get phone
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPhone()
    {
        return $this->phone;
    }

    /**
     * Set open24h
     *
     * @param boolean $open24h
     *
     * @return Business
     */
    public function setOpen24h($open24h)
    {
        $this->open24h = $open24h;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get open24h
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getOpen24h()
    {
        return $this->open24h;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getBusinessHours(): ?array
    {
        return $this->businessHours;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $businessHours
     */
    public function setBusinessHours(array $businessHours)
    {
        $this->businessHours = $businessHours;
    }

    public function addBusinessHours(array $businessHours)
    {
        $this->businessHours->add($businessHours);
    }

    public function removeBusinessHours(array $businessHours)
    {
        $this->businessHours->removeElement($businessHours);
    }

    /**
     * Set pageViews
     *
     * @param integer $pageViews
     *
     * @return Business
     */
    public function setPageViews($pageViews)
    {
        $this->pageViews = $pageViews;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get pageViews
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getPageViews()
    {
        return $this->pageViews;
    }

    /**
     * Set googlePlacesPlaceId
     *
     * @param string $googlePlacesPlaceId
     *
     * @return Business
     */
    public function setGooglePlacesPlaceId($googlePlacesPlaceId)
    {
        $this->googlePlacesPlaceId = $googlePlacesPlaceId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get googlePlacesPlaceId
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getGooglePlacesPlaceId()
    {
        return $this->googlePlacesPlaceId;
    }

    /**
     * Set foursquareVenueId
     *
     * @param string $foursquareVenueId
     *
     * @return Business
     */
    public function setFoursquareVenueId($foursquareVenueId)
    {
        $this->foursquareVenueId = $foursquareVenueId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get foursquareVenueId
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFoursquareVenueId()
    {
        return $this->foursquareVenueId;
    }

    // Member Methods for Relationships.
    // ---------------------------------

    /**
     * Set Merchant
     *
     * @param Merchant $merchant
     *
     * @return Business
     */
    public function setMerchant(Merchant $merchant)
    {
        $this->merchant = $merchant;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get Merchant
     *
     * @return Merchant
     */
    public function getMerchant()
    {
        return $this->merchant;
    }

    /**
     * Set Address
     *
     * @param Address $address
     *
     * @return Business
     */
    public function setAddress(Address $address)
    {
        $this->address = $address;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get Address
     *
     * @return Address
     */
    public function getAddress()
    {
        return $this->address;
    }

    /**
     * Get Reviews.
     *
     * @return ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getReviews()
    {
        return $this->reviews;
    }

    /**
     * Set Reviews.
     *
     * @param ArrayCollection $reviews
     *
     * @return Business
     */
    public function setReviews(ArrayCollection $reviews)
    {
        $this->reviews = $reviews;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Add review.
     *
     * @param Review $review
     *
     * @return Business
     */
    public function addReview(Review $review)
    {
        $this->reviews[] = $review;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get Business Type.
     *
     * @return BusinessType
     */
    public function getBusinessType()
    {
        return $this->businessType;
    }

    /**
     * Set Business Type.
     *
     * @param BusinessType $businessType
     *
     * @return Business
     */
    public function setBusinessType(BusinessType $businessType)
    {
        $this->businessType = $businessType;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get Images.
     *
     * @return ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getImages()
    {
        return $this->images;
    }

    /**
     * Set Images.
     *
     * @param ArrayCollection $images
     *
     * @return Business
     */
    public function setImages(ArrayCollection $images)
    {
        $this->images = $images;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Add image
     *
     * @param Image $image
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function addImage(Image $image)
    {
        $this->images[] = $image;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get Promotions.
     *
     * @return ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getPromotions()
    {
        return $this->promotions;
    }

    /**
     * Set Promotions.
     *
     * @param ArrayCollection $promotions
     *
     * @return Business
     */
    public function setPromotions(ArrayCollection $promotions)
    {
        $this->promotions = $promotions;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Add Promotion
     *
     * @param Promotion $promotion
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function addPromotion(Promotion $promotion)
    {
        $this->promotions[] = $promotion;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get Products
     * @return Product
     */
    public function getProducts()
    {
        return $this->products;
    }

    /**
     * Set Product
     *
     * @param Product $products
     */
    public function setProducts(Product $products)
    {
        $this->products = $products;
    }

    public function addProduct(Product $product)
    {
        $this->products[] = $product;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Check if the business is open
     */
    public function isOpen()
    {
        $curDate = new DateTime();
        $curDay = (int)$curDate->format('N');
        $curTime = $curDate->format('H:i:s');
        $businessHours = $this->getBusinessHours();
        $isOpen = $this->getOpen24h();

        if (!$this->getOpen24h()) {
            foreach ($businessHours as $hoursSet) {
                $openTime = date('H:i:s', strtotime($hoursSet['open_time']['date']));
                $closeTime = date('H:i:s', strtotime($hoursSet['close_time']['date']));

                if (in_array($curDay, $hoursSet["day"]) && $curTime >= $openTime && $curTime <= $closeTime) {
                    $isOpen = true;
                };
            }
        }

        return $isOpen;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->getName();
    }
}
```

**BusinessController**

```
public function editAction(Request $request, Business $business)
{
    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($business);

    //createForm seems to be giving me the error.
    $editForm = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\BusinessType', $business);

    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

        //TODO: translations
        $this->addFlash(
            'success',
            'Saved Changes'
        );

        return $this->redirectToRoute('business_edit', ['id' => $business->getId()]);
    }

    return $this->render('business/edit.html.twig',
        [
            'business' => $business,
            'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        ]
    );
}
```

**BusinessType**

```
    $builder->add('businessHours',
        CollectionType::class,
        [
            'entry_type' => BusinessHoursType::class,
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
        ]
    );
```

**BusinessHoursType**

```
class BusinessHoursType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('day',
            ChoiceType::class,
            [
                'label' => 'label.day',
                'translation_domain' => 'base',
                'choices' => array_flip(DateConstants::DAYS),
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => true,
            ]
        );
        $builder->add('open_time',
            TimeType::class,
            [
                'label' => 'label.open_time',
                'translation_domain' => 'business',
                'input' => 'datetime',
                'minutes' => [
                    0,
                    15,
                    30,
                    45,
                ],
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'time-selector',
                ],
            ]
        );
        $builder->add('close_time',
            TimeType::class,
            [
                'label' => 'label.close_time',
                'translation_domain' => 'business',
                'input' => 'datetime',
                'minutes' => [
                    0,
                    15,
                    30,
                    45,
                ],
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'time-selector',
                ],
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

Everything get saved in my database as 1 property named business_hours as follows:

```
[{"day":[1,3],"open_time":{"date":"1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe\/Brussels"},"close_time":{"date":"1970-01-01 21:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe\/Brussels"}}]
```

My **newAction** is as follows (which works and saved everything in the database including the business hours

```
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $business = new Business();

    $form = $this->createForm(BusinessType::class, $business);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $address = $form->get('address')->getData();
        $business->setAddress($address);

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($address);
        $em->persist($business);
        $em->flush();

        $this->addFlash(
            'success',
            $this->get('translator')->trans('business.message.created')
        );

        return $this->redirectToRoute('business_show', ['id' => $business->getId()]);
    }

    return $this->render('business/new.html.twig',
        [
            'business' => $business,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]
    );
 }
```

Comment: What does your entity look like?

Comment: @JasonRoman I edited and included my entity in the question.

Comment: I suspect it has to do with storing the type as a `json_array`